# How to open an arbitrary folder by typing its name after having typed a hot key or the like?

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys, launchy

I'd like to be able yo open any folder on my Win7 computer like mentioned in the question title.

[Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Everything search engine](http://www.voidtools.com/), to which you can also assign a hotkey if required.

Type enough of the name to identify the folder, since the shown selection is further refined with every character that you type.

Once the folder is on the screen, double-click to open in Explorer, or right-click for more options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can open folders from the run box, so the "hot key" would be <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.

Start by typing `C:\` (or your favorite drive letter) and as you type the available folders are listed. Down-arrow to select one if that's faster than typing, then another slash for the next level. Once you make it to the desired folder hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `OK` to load it up in Windows Explorer. Job done.

Not necessarily the *fastest* approach. But doesn't require any extra software.

Comment: I did know about this option, and simply want to type the name of the folder, not the entire path, which oftentimes aren't even known.

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to press a hot key that will enable you to type a path and have windows explorer open the path?

If that is the case, you can use Launchy like you had mentioned.

1. Open Launchy
2. Select *Windows Explorer* (I just need to type *w* and Windows Explorer is selected)
3. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>
4. Type the path
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Windows Explorer should then be opened with the path you entered.  Launchy has some auto completion available when typing the path as well.

Comment: You haven't understood the question correctly. "its name" means, well, its name, i.e. not its path or the name name of Windows Explorer, nor anything else...

Thanks for trying!